# How to build a CordApp with my own Corda Branch?

Tags: corda

We are a Project Group of our University and for our Project we want to change the Hash Function used by Corda. For this we downloaded the current Corda Version and are about to make our changes.

To Test this we need our Test CordApp to be Build using our Modified Version of Corda. The default Gradle Build included in the CordApp Template seems to include copy of a Specific Version of Corda.

How can we change this to our own Version and in the Best Case set a direct link to our own compiled .jar file outputs?

This is what I found for reference in the gradle.build:

```
corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
corda_release_version = '3.3-corda'
corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.2.1'
```

We are pretty new to Corda and Gradle and can't seem to find even a starting point for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not my area of expertise but I think this is what you will want to do:

1. Fork OS repo
2. Make your changes
3. Publish the artefacts to a local maven repository or to some like Artifactory (which Corda uses) - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_overview.html. The Corda Gradle setup should have this sort of stuff defined somewhere but probably needs redirecting.
4. In another project reference your local maven repo to retrieve the artefacts
5. Pray that it works

Comment: Hey, thanks for the Quick reply. We have done Step 1 and 2. I wasn't aware of how gradle handles publishing. I was hoping it could just throw all .jar files into a specified directory.
Step 4 is also the step that gives us the most trouble... I add what we found for configuration to the post.

Comment: There is also a way to get your dependencies from the file system, so you don't have to go through the maven/artefactory headache https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:declaring_file_dependency